# Get filenames from addon domain folder in php

Tags: php

I am not able to get the filenames from one level up and three levels down:

My current path is in 
`home/site/public_html/current_folder/`

I want to go to fetch all the file names inside `down3`
`home/site/public_html/www.down1.com/down2/down3/`

```
$path= dirname(__DIR__)."/www.down1.com/down2/down3/*.*";
$files= glob($path);
```

The above path is not working as I get `count($files) == 0`

Also the content of `$path` is  `\/home\/site\/public_html\/www.down1.com\/down2\/down3\/*.*`

with a `\` character in front of `/` in the above path

`www.down1.com` is an addon domain.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in [here](https://my.godaddy.com/help/what-is-my-websites-root-directory-16191)

Had to remove "www" from www.down1.com

```
$path= dirname(__DIR__)."/down1.com/down2/down3/*.*";
```

**What is my website's root directory?**

The root directory of your website is the content that loads when visitors access your domain name in a Web browser. The most obvious consequence of this is that you need to put your "index file" in your website's root directory for visitors to see your site at all ([more info](https://my.godaddy.com/help/what-file-displays-when-someone-browses-to-my-domain-name-16026)).

Website-related applications might also need to know your website's root directory.

Your website's root directory depends on whether the domain name is your primary domain name or another type ([more info](https://my.godaddy.com/help/manage-hosting-account-domains-4688)).

Your primary domain name's root directory is httpdocs/.

Secondary and subdomain names' root directories were specified when they were set up. You can find them listed in Plesk.

To Find Secondary (Addon) and Subdomains' Root Directories

Log in to your GoDaddy account.
Click Hosting.
Next to the account you want to use, click Manage.
In the section for each domain name, the root directory displays in the Website at field. By default, the root directory is the domain name itself followed by a forward slash, e.g. subdomain.coolexample.com/